# sympy.printing.mathmlで括弧()の扱いについて

Tags: python, sympy, mathjax

以下のように、Pythonの文字列をsimpifyで数式に変換し、
mathmlコマンドで数式をMathML形式に変換すると

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.printing.mathml import mathml

print(mathml(sympify("(2*x + 3*y + 1)*(4*x**2 - 6*x*y - 2*x + 9*y**2 - 3*y + 1)"),printer='presentation'))
```

以下のようなコードが出力されます。

```
<mrow><mrow><mrow><mn>2</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>x</mi></mrow><mo>+</mo><mrow><mn>3</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>y</mi></mrow><mo>+</mo><mn>1</mn></mrow><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mrow><mrow><mn>4</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><msup><mi>x</mi><mn>2</mn></msup></mrow><mo>-</mo><mrow><mn>6</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>x</mi><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>y</mi></mrow><mo>-</mo><mrow><mn>2</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>x</mi></mrow><mo>+</mo><mrow><mn>9</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><msup><mi>y</mi><mn>2</mn></msup></mrow><mo>-</mo><mrow><mn>3</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>y</mi></mrow><mo>+</mo><mn>1</mn></mrow></mrow>
```

出力されたコードをHTMLに埋め込んで以下のようにしてみました。

**test.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script async="" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.2/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
</head>
<body>
<math>
<mrow><mrow><mrow><mn>2</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>x</mi></mrow><mo>+</mo><mrow><mn>3</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>y</mi></mrow><mo>+</mo><mn>1</mn></mrow><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mrow><mrow><mn>4</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><msup><mi>x</mi><mn>2</mn></msup></mrow><mo>-</mo><mrow><mn>6</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>x</mi><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>y</mi></mrow><mo>-</mo><mrow><mn>2</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>x</mi></mrow><mo>+</mo><mrow><mn>9</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><msup><mi>y</mi><mn>2</mn></msup></mrow><mo>-</mo><mrow><mn>3</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>y</mi></mrow><mo>+</mo><mn>1</mn></mrow></mrow>
</math>
</body>
</html>
```

しかし、このコードだと、下記の画像のように括弧が欠けた出力になってしまいます。
これはやはりライブラリ側のコードを書き換えるしかないでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: アドホックな対処としては `"<mfenced>" + mathml(S("2*x + 3*y + 1"),printer='presentation') + "</mfenced>" + "<mfenced>" + mathml(S("4*x**2 - 6*x*y - 2*x + 9*y**2 - 3*y + 1"),printer='presentation') + "</mfenced>"` などでしょうか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

原因は[ここ](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/printing/mathml.py#L606)での処理にあります。

```python
for term in terms:
    x = self._print(term)
    mrow.appendChild(x)
```

Integral や power(`**`) などでは演算の優先順位を評価して、必要な場合には式を `()` で囲む処理が行われています。ですので、multiply でも以下の様に変更すると期待する出力が得られる様になります。

```python
for term in terms:
    mrow.appendChild(self.parenthesize(term, PRECEDENCE['Mul']))
```

sympy の repository に pull request を送ってみるのが順当な対処なのでしょうが、手っ取り早く MathMLPresentationPrinter._print_Mul メソッドを置き換えてしまう方法もあります。ただし、置き換えるのは特定のインスタンスオブジェクトの _print_Mul メソッドのみです。

```python
from sympy import *
from sympy.core.function import _coeff_isneg
from sympy.printing.mathml import mathml, MathMLPresentationPrinter
from sympy.printing.precedence import precedence_traditional, PRECEDENCE
import types

def _patched_print_Mul(self, expr):
    def multiply(expr, mrow):
        from sympy.simplify import fraction
        numer, denom = fraction(expr)
        if denom is not S.One:
            frac = self.dom.createElement('mfrac')
            if self._settings["fold_short_frac"] and len(str(expr)) < 7:
                frac.setAttribute('bevelled', 'true')
            xnum = self._print(numer)
            xden = self._print(denom)
            frac.appendChild(xnum)
            frac.appendChild(xden)
            mrow.appendChild(frac)
            return mrow
        coeff, terms = expr.as_coeff_mul()
        if coeff is S.One and len(terms) == 1:
            mrow.appendChild(self._print(terms[0]))
            return mrow
        if self.order != 'old':
            terms = Mul._from_args(terms).as_ordered_factors()
        if coeff != 1:
            x = self._print(coeff)
            y = self.dom.createElement('mo')
            y.appendChild(self.dom.createTextNode(self.mathml_tag(expr)))
            mrow.appendChild(x)
            mrow.appendChild(y)
        for term in terms:
            mrow.appendChild(self.parenthesize(term, PRECEDENCE['Mul']))
            if not term == terms[-1]:
                y = self.dom.createElement('mo')
                y.appendChild(self.dom.createTextNode(self.mathml_tag(expr)))
                mrow.appendChild(y)
        return mrow
    mrow = self.dom.createElement('mrow')
    if _coeff_isneg(expr):
        x = self.dom.createElement('mo')
        x.appendChild(self.dom.createTextNode('-'))
        mrow.appendChild(x)
        mrow = multiply(-expr, mrow)
    else:
        mrow = multiply(expr, mrow)
    return mrow

## Replace _print_Mul method
s = MathMLPresentationPrinter()
s._print_Mul = types.MethodType(_patched_print_Mul, s)
s.doprint(S("(2*x + 3*y + 1)*(4*x**2 - 6*x*y - 2*x + 9*y**2 - 3*y + 1)"))
```

**出力**

```html
<mrow><mfenced><mrow><mrow><mn>2</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>x</mi></mrow><mo>+</mo><mrow><mn>3</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>y</mi></mrow><mo>+</mo><mn>1</mn></mrow></mfenced><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mfenced><mrow><mrow><mn>4</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><msup><mi>x</mi><mn>2</mn></msup></mrow><mo>-</mo><mrow><mn>6</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>x</mi><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>y</mi></mrow><mo>-</mo><mrow><mn>2</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>x</mi></mrow><mo>+</mo><mrow><mn>9</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><msup><mi>y</mi><mn>2</mn></msup></mrow><mo>-</mo><mrow><mn>3</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>y</mi></mrow><mo>+</mo><mn>1</mn></mrow></mfenced></mrow>
```

[image: 数式]

Comment: ローカルでメソッド置き換える分には、求めているコードは出ました。勝手ながらプルリクエストを送ってみたのですが、テストでエラーが出るようです。https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/16985　sympyをcloneした後に、以下のコマンドを実行するとエラーチェックできるようです。`./bin/test mathml`

Comment: ありがとうございます。エラーがでる件は sympy の開発者にお任せしたいと思います。。。